# Client/Server interactions using the Telegram.org API

Tags: python, api, telegram

I'd like to understand the sequence of events when sending a method to the telegram server.

For example, if I send the `get_future_salts` method I am expecting from the server a response of type `FutureSalts`, but what I receive is a type of `MessageContainer` (which I'm having trouble parsing, but that is a separate issue).

If I ignore the `MessageContainer` object and simply request the next response from the server I receive the expected `FutureSalts` object.

Will there always be a `MessageContainer` object returned for each method called? If so, do I need to parse and process these `MessageContainer` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not always.

The server however usually packs multiple messages into containers.

I would advise that you decode all the data returned from the server.

You then have a full view /log of all that is being returned, then you can decide on what needs to be replied to.

Comment: I also receive `RpcResult` types back in some cases, which consist of `req_msg_id:long` and `result:Object`. But `Object` is not defined as a specific type. Is it an object that needs to be deserialized?

Comment: the result field has a header that identifies its type

Comment: So, deserialize the first integer in `Object` to get the type id? Is that what you mean by `header`?

Comment: If so, the deserialized type id is a `Config` data type but from an older layer (**23**) schema. I am using a layer **54** schema and have already executed `invokeWithLayer` as **54**. Do I have to wrap every command with `invokeWithLayer` to receive types from that layer?

Comment: BTW: I am expecting a `Config` type id so that is good. But trying to deserialize a data element from the wrong layer doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, instead of layer **54** above I mean layer **53**. Layer **54** doesn't yet exist. But I still have the same problem.

Comment: @KennyCason yes deserializing first integer gives the typeid

Comment: @KennyCason you jurt startoff your session invoking the layer you need. subesquent messages are assumed to be in that layer, eg 54

Comment: Yes, thank you. That seems to work. Now I'm dealing with `Objects` that are gzipped! If I get stuck I'll post another question. I truly appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: @KennyCason no problem, please kindly accept the answers if it solved your problems. It serves as a guide for future users